# Why in Nyquist Theorems, for each hz of bandwidth, 2 symbol can be carried?

Tags: signals, signal-processing

The Nyquist bit transfer rate equation: C_max = 2WLog_2(M)

The max bits transfer rate is 2 times of analogue bandwidth times bits carried per symbol

Why each Hz can carry 2 symbols? Wouldn't each cycle of wave represent exactly 1 symbol?

How is this related to the Nyquist sampling Theorems? Sampling theorem is about recovering an analogue signal from the digital signal without loss, but isn't the equation about recover the digital signal from an analogue signal?

Answer (score 1):

A sine wave and a cosine wave (or a sine wave shifted 90 degrees in phase) are mathematically orthogonal, and thus a 1 Hz signal of each can be transmitted without interfering with the other, as long as the two phases are carefully kept orthogonal at the transmitter, and tracked separately at the receiver (thus requiring some kind of initial phase synchronization mechanism).  Each orthogonal carrier, at the theoretical limit, can carry 1 bit per unit time; thus 2 bits for the orthogonal pair.